# How to check if displayed input fields are not empty?

Tags: jquery

I have a form, in which I need to check if certain fields have content, however these fields are not displayed all at the same time.  How can I check that the fields in the displayed div are not empty, and ignore the ones that are not displayed.

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v6snz8k6/3/ - I am referring to processStep3()

```
function processStep3() {
    var measures = $('.meausres').length;
    if (measures > 0) {
        alert ("yes");
    } else {
        alert ("no");
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's your HTML, what's your JavaScript or jQuery to show/hide the elements? How is your own attemp failing? Please see the "[mcve]" guidelines for posting relevant code in your questions, don't just link to it and expect us to follow you. Incidentally you seem to have a typo in your selector `.meausres` rather than `.measures`.

Comment: All the code is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: And yet it *should* be *in your question*.

Comment: I see ... Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 issues:

1. You have a wrong class name MEAUSRES when I guess you wanna use measures.
2. $('.measures').length <-- will get the number of .measures elements not the length of the content.
3. You need to loop over the visible elements only with the selector `:visible` and a `.each` loop

try with this:

```
function processStep3() {
    var flagEmpty = false;
    $('.measures:visible').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="") flagEmpty = true;
    });
    if (!flagEmpty) {
        alert ("OK! there's no empty inputs");
    } else {
        alert ("oops! there's empty inputs");
    }   
}
```